# abs 'implicit declaration...' error after including math.h

Tags: c, math.h, absolute-value

I used the `abs()` function and I added `#include <math.h>` at the top of code. But I keep getting this error:

```
hello.c:20:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'abs' is invalid in C99
[-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      int a = abs(arrOfHour[i] - hour) * 60 + minute;
              ^
```

I'm using LLVM compiler.

Why does this error occurs even though I have included `math.h`?

Comment: Can you post the code, especially the part you call `abs`?

Comment: @holgac , That isn't needed. The part where the OP calls `abs` is in the warning message.

Comment: @CoolGuy yeah I forgot undeclared functions are implicitly declared, sorry. Anyway, for future, you can check where a function is declared using *manpages*, http://linux.die.net/man/3/abs

Comment: BTW: Suspect code's `int a = abs(arrOfHour[i] - hour) * 60 + minute;` and its previous calculation of `minute` will not work as desired.  Maybe want something like `a = abs(arrOfHour[i]*60 + arrOfMin[i] - (hour*60 + min))`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm going to quote straight from the docs : ["Prototypes for abs, labs and llabs are in stdlib.h"](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Absolute-Value.html)

As a rule of thumb the mathematical functions that operate on floating point numbers are in math.h, and the ones that operate on integers are in stdlib.h.

There's a [pretty good Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mathematical_functions) on C mathematical functions if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

The function headers are missing, but since the abs function requires the library `math.h` and also `stdlib.h`, the latter must be missing.
It also includes the call to the library `stdlib.h`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```