# Error: implicit declaration of function [c]

Tags: c, c89

I included `math.h` library and used `abs` function and this error shows:

```
error: implicit declaration of function ‘abs’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
razlika=(abs(x3) / ((x1+x2)/2))*100;
^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: Please remove c++ tag if you are using c language, and paste the error as text please, so other users can find the error

Comment: Please post relevant warnings and code *as text* in the question. Images are useless for most purposes.

Comment: Don't use a screenshot when you can show identical text. Screenshots won't show up in text searches, making this question almost impossible to discover.

Comment: Please include text, not screenshots of text. This helps us to help you, because we can easily copy the text to do searches, and it helps search engines index the question properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [abs 'implicit declaration...' error after including math.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577833/abs-implicit-declaration-error-after-including-math-h)

Comment: _"Used abs function"_ Used it how? Where is your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `stdlib.h`, not `math.h`.

Implicit declaration errors are generally due to missing/incorrect header files.

Comment: Thank you, works flawlessly.